# Android: Reporting drop result: false

Tags: java, android, drag-and-drop

I wanted to programm a drag and drop button wich you can move where you want.
I tryed it with onDrag(), but if i want to drop the button i get the message:
"**Reporting drop result: false** "
I dont know why. 
The other problem is that the shadowbuilder just disappear if I drop the button.
I want to convert the shadow to a normal button if I drop it.

I'll be very grateful, if someone could help me.

```
@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    ClipData clipdata = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
    View parent = (View) v.getParent();
    parent.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder((View) v.getParent());
    v.startDrag(clipdata, shadowBuilder,parent, 0);

    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {


    int dragaction = event.getAction();



    if (dragaction == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED) {


        if (event.getClipDescription().hasMimeType(ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)) {
            //returns true, when view can is the view of onLongClick
            Log.e("drag start", "drag started");

        }
        return true;

    } else {

        if (event.getAction() ==   DragEvent.ACTION_DROP){
            v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }


    return true;
}
```